# Is this :compiler script configured properly for pylint, a python linter?

Tags: vimscript, makeprg

I am pretty new to Vim and coding in general. I'm trying to improve my compile-edit-compile cycle for Python. I just learned about Vim's :make and quickfix system; it's really cool. I would like to do static analysis to catch syntax errors etc.

I have NVim running and in my `nvim/runtime/compiler/` directory I have a file called `pylint.vim`. I think it came as a default. Here is the text of it:

```vimscript
" Vim compiler file
" Compiler: Pylint for Python
" Maintainer: Daniel Moch <daniel@danielmoch.com>
" Last Change: 2016 May 20

if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = "pylint"

if exists(":CompilerSet") != 2      " older Vim always used :setlocal
  command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
endif

CompilerSet makeprg=pylint\ --output-format=text\ --msg-template=\"{path}:{line}:{column}:{C}:\ [{symbol}]\ {msg}\"\ --reports=no
CompilerSet errorformat=%A%f:%l:%c:%t:\ %m,%A%f:%l:\ %m,%A%f:(%l):\ %m,%-Z%p^%.%#,%-G%.%#
```

When I use the `:make` command with this compile script set using `:compile pylint`, I get the following output of the terminal:

```
:!pylint --output-format=text --msg-template="{path}:{line}:{column}:{C}: [{symbol}] {msg}" --report
s=no  2>&1| tee /tmp/nvimXypd20/2

Usage: pylint [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --long-help           more verbose help.

  Master:
    --init-hook=<code>  Python code to execute, usually for sys.path
                        manipulation such as pygtk.require().
```

I have omitted the rest of the long pylint stuff.

So this `makeprg` is configured to run without any filepaths as arguments to the bash command? Is that the normal way of doing it? Should I just use `:make %` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you probably want to use `:make %`. The version presented is flexible in that you can pass filenames other than the current one.

But you can always `:setlocal makeprg+=\ %` after the `:compiler pylint` so that `:make` uses the current file.